# How do I change Naulilus to preserve the original date (created)

Tags: nautilus

16.04 File browser (Nautilus) shows date **modified** for files.
I can change certain options but how do I change the view to preserve the **original date** (created) not (modified)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy: there is no such thing on a UNIX filesystem. See countless sources, for example "[Timestamp, modification time, and created time of a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file)" on Unix & Linux SE. The point is that UNIX-like file systems do not store a file creation date. You have an *access* date (which on modern Linux filesystems shows by default the last time the file was accessed with a precision of 24 hours), a *modification* date (the last time data was changed) and a *change* date (the last time metadata such as permissions was changed).

As far as I know Nautilus cannot show anything else but the data modification date.